# Javascript: Ajax $.post Cookie File Issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

I'm logging into a website using PHP cURL -- it generates a cookie file once logged in succesfully.

```
    $cookieFile = tempnam("/tmp", "curl-cookie"); // Cookie file to login.
```

The php script is being executed by an ajax $.get request to the php file.

Now since I'm logged in, i want to navigate (not really 'navigate', just directly make a $.post request) to another page, but i wanna do this in Javascript/Ajax; however the only way to stay authenticated for the page to load successfully is for the cookies to be read. I'm trying to figure out how i can set all the cookies in the cookie file into the header of the $.post request so i get the appropriate response and not a "you need to login" response.

I'm sure it seems a bit odd. But that's what I'm trying to do. Any ideas?

Also keep in mind, i'm trying to send cookies to another domain, not my own. Not sure if that is an issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing the authentication server side, gathering a cookie, that you would like to replay for further access, those access need to be done also server side.

From the client point of view, cookies are strored in the browser. For obvious security reasons, a webpage cannot modify the cookie storage of a client, hence you cannot "add" the cookie copied from your server, to any client, that you would like to be authentified.

The target website should expose a cross site js API, like Facebook, gmail or other such API, in order to identify your clients against it.